# PHPExcel corrupt file Drop down list not working Windows Excel Data validation

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

If I use:

```
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
$objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
$objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
$objValidation->setFormula1('"male,female"');
```

to create an excel file, I get the following errors on windows Excel

```
1. We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want to recover....
2. Removed Feature: Data validation from /xl/worksheets/shee1.xml part
```

If I comment that code out it opens normally.

Works as expected on Ubuntu Libre Office.

Comment: @MarkBaker updated to show more code. As mentioned this works perfectly on Libre office ( linux ) , Its MS Excel that breaks it.

Comment: Any particular version of MS Excel? Data validation has been working with most versions of Excel without any change for a long while

Comment: @MarkBaker Latest version available from Office 365

Comment: I'm running Office 2016 as my most recent version, and it works exactly as expected; but I haven't access to office 365

Comment: Generated file passes data validation using the MS Open XML SDK Productivity Tool against 2007, 2010 and 2013 standards.

Comment: @MarkBaker I check with an online XMLvalidator and it says that I have extra content at the end.

Comment: I don't know what extra content that would be.... what online validator did you use?

Comment: @MarkBaker http://xmlgrid.net/validator.html

Comment: Feeding the xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml (which contains the data validation markup) through that validator, I get `This document was successfully checked as well-formed XML!`.... what are you validating to give that "extra content" message?

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you for taking the time to resolve this issue. this is the sheet: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9cxXLHAyTVZcUxzWGNyWlM4SG8

Comment: Is it possible to send me the actual file itself?

Comment: @MarkBaker My previous comment has a link to Gdrive where you can download the file. will that suffice?

Comment: That actually opens the file in my browser, I'm not sur ethat it allows download of the original file (as generated by PHPExcel)

Comment: @MarkBaker Let me know if Dropbox works, it opens the file but also has a separate Download option: https://www.dropbox.com/s/726fjybru6kqqj3/program-participants-grantee-survey.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all explained in the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell)

And if you look at the examples such as `15datavalidation.php`, it demonstrates how to create List type data validations

```
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('B5')
    ->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
...
$objValidation->setFormula1('"Item A,Item B,Item C"');
```

shows how to create a list of fixed values

```
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('B7')
    ->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
$objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
...
$objValidation->setFormula1('$D$2:$D$6');
```

shows how to create a list using a formula

Example `39dropdown.php` even shows how to created linked lists, where the values in one list are dependent on the selected value of another

Comment: I can create and read the file with dropdowns without a problem in Libre Office, its only Microsoft Excel that is corrupted. I am using the latest version available from Office 365.